# Thai Month names from cultureInfo

Tags: c#, xamarin, io

when my clients device is set to Thai language. and I call CurrentCulture.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames I get an array of empty strings.
how do I get Thai Date Formats ?

Comment: What framework version is installed on that device? `TaiwanCalendar` or `TaiwanLunisolarCalendar`??

Comment: Thai (like Thailand) not Taiwan (from my reading). I'm pretty sure they share nearly nothing of the same culture/locale. What kind of device? What OS? Is there a Thai localized package installed on the device?

Comment: iOS 12/13 and when i use NSDateFormatter it works fine

Comment: Oh yes I am using ThaiBuddhistCalendar

Comment: I have exactly same problem. I always get empty string from CurrentCulture.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames for Thai culture in WPF .net core 3.1 and Blazor WebAssembly .net core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NODA TIME](https://nodatime.org/)  ,  I use it and it is way better than  .net date and time

Answer (score 0):

One might want to add the months (and their code abbreviations) from a JSON file directly.

Here is a Markdown table with each month's name and codename (reading it would require to learn the Thai alphabet or to use some translation software such as Google Translate)

| Name | code |
| --- | --- |
| มกรา คม | ม.ค. |
| กุม ภา พัน ธ์ | ก.พ. |
| มีนา คม | มี.ค. |
| เมษา ยน | เม.ย. |
| พฤ ษภา คม | พ.ค. |
| มิถุนา ยน | มิ.ย. |
| กร(a)ก(a)ฎา คม | ก.ค. |
| สิงหา คม | ส.ค. |
| กันยา ยน | ก.ย. |
| ตุลา คม | ต.ค. |
| พฤศ จิ กา ยน | พ.ย. |
| ธัน วา คม | ธ.ค. |